# trying to make a redeem command for my discord bot. I want it to make the const not useable anymore

Tags: discord.js

I want to make once the code is redeemed it not be able to be used

```
const codes = ['5345345345345345','23123123123','312312312321q3']
for (var i = 0; i < codes.length; i++) {
    if (message.content.includes(`redeem ${codes[i]}`)) {

        message.channel.send("YES IT WORKED") 
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: ```const codes = ['5345345345345345','23123123123','312312312321q3']
for (var i = 0; i < codes.length; i++) {
  if (message.content.includes(`redeem ${codes[i]}`)) {

    message.channel.send("YES IT WORKED") 
          break;
}
}``` this is the full code i didnt do the question correct

Answer (score 2):

You can essentially use `Array.prototype.splice()` to remove elements from the array therefore modifying it, so i would do something like this

```js
const codes = ['5345345345345345','23123123123','312312312321q3'] 
for (var i = 0; i < codes.length; i++) {   
    if (message.content.includes(`redeem ${codes[i]}`)) {   
        // finding index of the code
        const index = codes.indexOf(codes[i]);
        //splicing from array
        codes.splice(index, 1) // splice(index of element, number of elements to delete)   
        message.channel.send("YES IT WORKED")            
        break; 
    } 
}
```